# Execute .R script within Python using Rscript.exe shell

Tags: python, r, rscript

I have an .R file saved locally at the following path:

```
Rfilepath = "C:\\python\\buyback_parse_guide.r"
```

The command for RScript.exe is:

```
RScriptCmd = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe --vanilla"
```

I tried running:

```
subprocess.call([RScriptCmd,Rfilepath],shell=True)
```

But it returns 1 -- and the .R script did not run successfully. What am I doing wrong? I'm new to Python so this is probably a simple syntax error... I also tried these, but they all return 1:

```
subprocess.call('"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\Rscript.exe"',shell=True)

subprocess.call('"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe"',shell=True)

subprocess.call('C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\Rscript.exe',shell=True)

subprocess.call('C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe',shell=True)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The RScriptCmd needs to be just the executable, no command line arguments. So:

```
RScriptCmd = "\"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe\""
```

Then the Rfilepath can actually be all of the arguments - and renamed:

```
 RArguments = "--vanilla \"C:\\python\\buyback_parse_guide.r\""
```

Comment: It's still not working. I tried the above and did: subprocess.call([RScriptCmd,RArguments],shell=True)

Comment: what happens when you run that same command from the command prompt? Some programs incorrectly return a non-zero value on success (doubt that R would do this though)

Comment: C:\Program Files>C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\Rscript.exe --vanilla C:\python\
buyback_parse_guide.r 
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: I tried `RScriptCmd = "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-2.15.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe"` and `RArgs = "--vanilla C:\\python\\buyback_parse_guide.r"`. Didn't work either. Definitely a syntax error I'm not seeing

Comment: This is what works in cmd.exe: `"C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.2\bin\Rscript.exe" --vanilla C:\python\buyback_parse_guide.r`

Comment: see my changes above - its likely the reason @hd1 states - there is a space in "Program Files" so quoting the path to the executable should account for that

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a similar problem to mine. I had to reinstall RScript to a path which has no spaces.

See: [Running Rscript via Python using os.system() or subprocess()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514769/running-rscript-via-python-using-os-system-or-subprocess)

This is how I worked out the communication between Python and Rscript:

part in Python:

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen,call
p = subprocess.Popen([ path/to/RScript.exe, path/to/Script.R, Arg1], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out = p.communicate()
outValue = out[0]
```

`outValue` contains the output-Value after executing the Script.R

part in the R-Script:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
argument1 <- as.character(args[1])
...
write(output, stdout())
```

`output` is the variable to send to Python