# Python - Using subprocess to Pipe R Script, resultant Winerror 2

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to run an R Script through Python using `subprocess` but unfortunately, I'm continually getting the following error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is extremely frustrating as I've checked the path over everything multiple times (done it without C:/, moved to different directories, changed the R script I'm trying to run, etc). I've also checked the CompSec Environment Variable, and it is also correct (through Windows Systems, although I never checked it directly in my IDE, Spyder). I've tried doing it in Python 2.7 and Python 3.5, and neither version works.

The code goes as follows:

```
import subprocess

def sort_ByInputColumn(inputPath, inputFileTermination, sortColumn, outputPath, outputFileTermination):
scriptPath = "C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/Rscript_SortByInputColumn.R"
subprocess.call(["Rscript",  scriptPath, inputPath, inputFileTermination, sortColumn, outputPath, outputFileTermination])

fileName = 'Alabama'
outputPath = "C:/Users/Kyle/Documents/HillData/Data/Output/Module2/"
sortColumn = str(16)
inputTermination = fileName + 'Module2NN_WorkCounty_Work.csv'
outputFileTermination = fileName + 'Module2NN_SortedWorkCounty.csv'
sort_ByInputColumn(outputPath, inputTermination, sortColumn, outputPath, outputFileTermination)
```

The fact that I get this error no matter what code I try to run (even blatantly copy-pasting [this tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/integrating-python-and-r-part-ii-executing-r-from-python-and-vice-versa/) to try and make it work) makes me feel like something deeper (or something extremely obvious) is going on that I'm not seeing.

Would appreciate any feedback on the matter.

Comment: Can you run the command in cmd?

Comment: Try providing the full path to the executable (assuming _Rscript_ is the program you want to run).

Comment: Prefix your script command by "cmd /c". Unless it is an executable, the `subprocess` module won't exec it for you (unlike `os.system`)

Comment: @handle I tried doing that, I got the same error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre What do you mean?

Comment: @genap  Jean-FrançoisFabre is pointing out that subprocess does not resolve which executable to open your script with (system default handler). But this does not apply here as you are providing the executable, albeit without absolut path (so it at least needs to be in environment variable).

Comment: @genap Try it as Natecat suggests: print( " ".join( callist ) ) and run it manually. Try to find out which args are actually passed to the target program. Try quoting path arguments or convert them to local abs path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this most annoying and horrendous problem, I reinstalled R into a directory with no spaces and called `Rscript` with its full pathing (that is `"C:/R/R-3.3.1/bin/Rscript.exe"` from `C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/bin/Rscript.exe"` because `Program Files` has a space and this kills `subprocess` because it's command line based, I guess). This time, it worked.

See [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28514769/running-rscript-via-python-using-os-system-or-subprocess) for a hint as to where I got the inspiration for this.